# dtype is not exist for my data frame column and want to assign the dtype 'Object'

Tags: python, pandas

When I tried to display the dtype of a column(Period) in my dataframe it is giving the below error.
and I want to assign the datatype as object.

KeyError: 'Period'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-234-e1689ba33c98> in <module>
----> 1 df['Period'].dtype

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
```

[image: dateframe]

Comment: It's your index. You can not change the data type of the index. If you want to treat it like a column, do first: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you’re trying to do here? Why do you want your index to be of the object dtype? Also, your title is incorrect, please reread the error message.